# Build SAPUI5 App with Grunt/Gulp and deploy form Eclipse with ABAP Team Provider

Tags: javascript, eclipse, gruntjs, gulp, sapui5

I am trying to optimize an existing UI5 application which resides in SAP BW as BSP Application and runs from SAP Portal (You press on the link and the UI5 application opens in a new Tab).

My main concern is with the amount of calls between Client and Back-end system. Especially calling all the library.css/library-preload.js/etc files AND custem controller.js and view.js files.

I found possible solutions involving grunt/gulp or deploying from SAP WebIDE. I trying building and deploying the App with SAP WebIDE, but after opening the App, Network still shows a lot of traffic + there is no Component-preload.js call. I'm guessing it has something to do with where the app is launched or I still have some configuring to do on the back-end?

I would like to build my App with either grunt/gulp since I can involve other plugins like lints, compression (for js, html, css), test, and many more. The problem is that the App resides not in OS, but somewhere in DB.

So I want to build my App with all those Grunt/Gulp tasks and deploy to ABAP AS (in BW as BSP application) using ABAP Team Provider and ensure that when I call the app from Portal, the files will be compressed/minified and, what is more important, **that all the relevant .js files will be loaded as a single request**.

Is what I imagine even possible? And if yes, then what are the steps required to accomplish this?

**NOTE:** I checked SCN and unfortunately I can't use your typical npm grunt or grunt-openui5 etc since the App resides somewhere in the DB :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a build configuration inside your WebIDE project, WebIDE will reate a DIST folder containing the distribution package.

Inside DIST there is an autogenerated Component-preload.js